# Is it possible to declare to mysql queries?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a code for a single button where it will perform either of two actions where it will add to the database if the user currently don't have the record while it will update the user's record if the user has records already. I've done it like this:

```
if() {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table...");
}
else {
   mysql_query("UPDATE table SET...");
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you've written will work. If you have a way to know if there already exists a row or not without making an additional query just for this bit of code, then do exactly as you wrote.

If, however, you planned to first `SELECT` from the table to see if a row exists, then conditionally `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, you will perform more queries than necessary.

It would be better to either:

1. Have a PRIMARY KEY or other constraint on the table prevent duplicate `INSERT`s. Then issue an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query. This will attempt to `INSERT` the row, and if it is a duplicate, automatically perform the specified `UPDATE` to that row instead.
2. Issue the `UPDATE` query and check `mysql_affected_rows` to see if it updated an existing row. If not, then issue the `INSERT` query to create the new row.

Which one is more appropriate depends on your application.

Comment: I like `UPDATE` and `affected_rows` - one less query. Only one problem, `_affected_rows` will also return 0 if it didn't have to update anything (record was present, but data was the same)

Comment: could you please give me an example of the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? when I'm using a SELECT first -shire

Comment: You do not make a SELECT first... that's the point. That text in my answer is linked to the manual page with examples.

Comment: What if the row that shouldn't be duplicated is not a primary key?

Comment: Make it part of the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index. If you are not allowing two rows for that entry, you should be expressing that through a database constraint.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly set unique keys, you should use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) so you could remove the `if`.

```
REPLACE INTO table VALUE (...);
```

Pay attention that this is a MySQL extension, thus not portable to other DBs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could try the insert then if it fails try the update.

But you could use the MYSQL sql "REPLACE" keyword, which will insert a new record if it doesn't exist or delete the existing record and insert your new one if it does.

You could also use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax
(explained here - [Link to MYSQL ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which seems to be the closest fit to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

first write a query for check that record is already exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , it will work